# Remove specific product variation from cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

I want to remove a variation product from the cart in wordpress, woocommerce.

I'm able to remove a simple product but not a variation product.
With this code I can remove a simple product.
I have tried passing in both the variation id and the parent variation id.
I have no idea why its not working, would appreciate if some got a clue.

```
$product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $aCurrentUserDataItem->id );
$cart_item_key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
( $cart_item_key ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a foreach loop as follow to target and remove a specific variation id from cart:

```php
$remove_variation_id = 41; // The variation id to remove

// loop through cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
    // If the targeted variation id is in cart
    if ( $item['variation_id'] == $remove_variation_id ) {
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $item_key ); // we remove it
        break; // stop the loop
    }
}
```

Tested and works.